# What are the benefits of redirecting main() method to another method on program start?

Tags: java

In the [Android Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/) repository I found  a [Main.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/tools/dexdeps/src/com/android/dexdeps/Main.java) file including this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.run(args);
}

void run(String[] args) {
    //CODE CONTUNIES
}
```

I found [some](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-create-object-main-class-class-contains-main/) articles saying creating instance of Main class is not allowed. I tried this in IntelliJ and it works. Is there any benefit of this or is it just a code beauty?

Comment: of course it works, but your class with your main method should have 1, and only 1 function, and that is to serve as entry point for your application.
You can write your entire codebase in your main method if you want, but why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Also you should generally avoid a method named `run` since it can be confused with `Runnable` interface and threading. For example `doSomething` or `process` can work well.

Comment: It's just a stylistic thing. There are no real benefits.

Answer (score 1):

The article you posted says only that the `JVM` does not create an instance of `Main` when running the application. This is why it's a `static` method.

---

As per benefits, I do not see any except for leaving the `main` method as clean as possible and move some cumbersome logic in an other place.

Unless you are using `Main.java` as an actual objects with fields and useful methods you should use other `static` methods to organize your logic.

The [class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/tools/dexdeps/src/com/android/dexdeps/Main.java) you posted, in fact, contains other methods besides `run`. They could as well have written another `class`. I feel it's more of a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the articles don't say that you can create instances of different objects in your main method!!! The articles said that it's not necessary to create an instance of a specific object to call the main method.

Let's suppose that you have the Application class where you have declared the main method. For calling the main method, you don't need to create an instance of Application like this Application app = new Application(), and after that to call the main method like this: app.main();